# how to get facebook friend full profile with email, using socialauth with extended permissions?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, socialauth

problem is what I can not fetch friends full profile with email usinq SocialAuth or facebook4j.

How to set permissions which can allow read contacts full profile

```
graph.facebook.com.custom_permissions = publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location,offline_access
```

here is a example which return only user firstname, lastname and id.

with facebook4j from friends list also I have null

```
Facebook facebook = (Facebook) request.getSession().getAttribute("facebook");
    if(facebook != null){
    ResponseList<Friend> list = facebook.getFriends();
    for (Friend fr : list) {
        User user = facebook.getUser(fr.getId(), new Reading().fields("email"));
     //   System.out.println("User!!!!!! " + fr.getId() + " + " + user.getFirstName() + "|" + user.getEmail());
    }
    }
```

I am reading fb api, but I am not sure what all clear, so what is the solution?
which permission I need?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot get emails of your friends using API

Comment: But I saw example in the internet which is get your fb contacts emails. For example it does hotmail. or you can find another examples, when whey get all friends full profile.